# Rsync for backups

Tags: hard-drive, backup, disk-utility, rsync, disk-volume

I have gotten into the habit of using `rsync` to do my own backups of an encrypted volume containing my personal info onto an external hard drive. I did not use Time Machine, because I do not own the whole hard drive, I just have a volume of 100 GB on the host hard drive. I created the volume using `Disk Utility`. When `rsync` copies that volume, it copies a succession of 8.4 MB opaque "bands" to the HDD (these "bands" are how a Volume is actually stored on disk - you can see by right-clicking to see the contents of the package on a `.dmg`).

My question is: can I restore that to a properly readable volume, should I need to recover data from my backup? I never had to try for real, and I hope to never have to, but I am wondering if this is actually a viable backup strategy, or if I wouldn't be able to restore a readable volume from those "bands".

Here is the `rsync` command I use:

```
rsync -arv --progress "/Users/frank/MyFile" /Volumes/Backup
```

Comment: Which command/arguments are you using to do the backup? Are you actually using `rsync` to backup the encrypted dmg or what is the meaning of "band"? Have you ever tried to access your backuped data (or to restore it)?

Comment: @patrix: I added the comment to my original post. I haven't tried to restore the data yet. I am not sure if the "bands" are an artifact of rsync, of of the Apple Volume.

Comment: Actually - I just checked - the bands are inside the .dmg seen as a package. If you right click on a .dmg and ask to see the packages contents, you will see it is made up of "bands".

Comment: Well, trying to restore it (to a different location) might be the better proof (or lack thereof) than any answer here could be :-)

Comment: True enough - I can try and report.